# how to print values in multiple textboxes in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a from where i have 10 textboxes and they are named as textbox1,textbox2 and so on. I want to print the values in all the textboxes in a single rich-textbox. is there any way i can do that.
the way i am doing it currently is:

```
richTextBox1.Text = label1.Text + "\t:\t" + textBox1.Text + "\n" + label1.Text + "\t:\t" + textBox1.Text;
```

but as you can see it will be very cumbersome to type it for all the textboxes.

Comment: use StringBuilder(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: is there anyway to loop on textbox name?

Comment: @Kratos why is there `label1.Text` here?

Comment: @KingKing......well thats my original code...i just asked for textbox because i can then apply same logic on labels also

Comment: @Kratos have you tried my code yet?

Comment: @KingKing....hey man i tried your code and it doesn't work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
   yourRichTextBox.Text += string.Format("{0}\t:\t{1}\r\n",
    yourForm.Controls["label" + i].Text, yourForm.Controls["textBox" + i].Text);
}
```

**NOTE**: if you use the code inside your form class, just replace `yourForm` with `this` or simply remove `yourForm`.

Comment: @Kratos **It's just because you typed `textbox` before, after re-scanning your question, it's `textBox`**, just replace `textbox` with `textBox` in my code.

Comment: @Kratos could you post your tested code? the code is so simple that I'm sure it should work. BTW, are your `textBoxes` placed on your form or any other container?

Comment: sorry man, completely my fault. your code just works fine.....and once again i m really sorry to bother it....

Comment: how can i use the above code for both label and textbox in same string join function.

Comment: @Kratos you have the corresponding `labels` from `label1` to `label10`?

Comment: @Kratos looks like you have 10 pairs of `labels` and `textBoxes` with appended numbers from `1 to 10`. See my updated code, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
private string ReadTextboxes()
{
    return textbox1.Text + textbox2.Text + textbox2.Text + ...
}

private string SetRichTextbox()
{
    richTextBox1.Text = ReadTextboxes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this...

```
 private string GetTextBoxStrings()
        {
            string richTextString = string.Empty;
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> TextBoxList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBoxList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(((TextBox)c).Name,((TextBox)c).Text));
                }
            }
            TextBoxList = TextBoxList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();

            foreach (var item in TextBoxList)
            {
                richTextString += item.Value + "\t:\t";
            }
            return richTextString;
        }
```

then call it and assign into richtextBox.

```
richTextBox1.Text = GetTextBoxStrings();
```